# Maven dependency plugin copy jar with dependencies

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to copy a jar from my local repository into another project as described here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

However my jar is coming out of maven-assembly-plugin as a "jar with dependencies", which puts the regular jar and the assembled jar in my local repo. The jar name looks something like:

example-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

and I can find it in the repo and use it if I copy manually. I thought it would be a good idea to let maven copy it so I used the dependency copy goal described above.

However I cant make it work so it copies the "jar with dependencies" jar.

This is how the pom looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>my.group</groupId>
              <artifactId>example-test</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>jar</type>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
              <destFileName>somename.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>

          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I tried to set the type to "jar-with-dependencies" but that didnt work. It only worked if I let the type as "jar" but then it copies the regular not assembled jar. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: IIRC there's no `type=jar-with-dependencies`; take these as guesses. I think it isn't working because the jar you want to copy doesn't exist yet. Or, better, around the middle of the page you linked, it says to bind the plugin to a phase **after** `install`. The other problem I can see is that the plugin will copy the artifact pointed to by the usual Maven coordinates `<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>`, and probably there's nothing that identifies your `jar-with-dependencies` - but I'm not really sure about this.

Comment: Is this other project a module of an existing project or a stand-a-lone project?

Comment: Well its a bit complicated, basically I tried setup Android with Maven but with no success and I spend way too much time on that since my android project depends on a single jar which isnt part of android which I just put in the "libs" folder but I had to do that every time I changed something in the jar's source... So I thought I could at least try using maven for this single thing, because I couldnt make the whole android-maven plugin to work

Comment: Also of course I could include the separate jars as well since at least that seems to work. Which means of course that its just another 2-3 artifacts there but I thought I could make it work as one jar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have an artifact like this:

```
example-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

You want to reference it like this:

```
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>my.group</groupId>
          <artifactId>example-test</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>jar</type>
          <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
          <overWrite>true</overWrite>
          <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
          <destFileName>somename.jar</destFileName>
        </artifactItem>
```

The example is here:

```
        <artifactItem>
          <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
          <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
          <version>[ version ]</version>
          <type>[ packaging ]</type>
  this---><classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
          <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
          <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
          <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
        </artifactItem>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This copies the all the required jar to the WEB-INF/lib , including the dependency jar